# Get selected value from a select filled by server to prevent a value to be used

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to get the values from this select:

```
<select class="ddlProfile drop" id="ddlProfile" runat="server"></select>
```

So I can use a javascript to prevent the value "0" to be used when selected.

The values of this select should be 0, 1 and 2, with their respective texts being "Select option", "Admin" and "Operator".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're using jQuery or not, so I'll write this with vanilla JS. But, you can attach a change event handler, test the selected option for the value you don't want (or want), and then do something if they've selected that option.

[See this jsfiddle for a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/48cuom72/2/)

```
document.getElementById('ddlProfile').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var valSought = this.value;
    if (valSought === "0") {
        //do something here because they picked the option with value 0
    }
}, false);
```

And here is the jQuery representation:

```
//I use document here so that dynamic elements can be supported
$(document).on('change', '#ddlProfile', function () {
    var valSought = $(this).val();
    if (valSought === "0") {
        //do something here because they picked the option with value 0
    }
});
```

The vanilla JS event listener will work regardless of whether you're using jQuery or not.

You may also want to get the value of `ddlProfile` at the time of any form submissions, AJAX calls, etc. and then do prevent the submission if the value is 0.

Comment: I am using JQuery, sorry I didn't mention it earlier, what should I change about the code?

Comment: When I try with vanilla javascript, I get a error telling me that I can't read property "addEventListener" of null.

Comment: Be sure to put this inside a script at the bottom of the `body` element or if you're running the script inside a `head` element, be sure to wrap this inside a `$(document).ready(function () { ... }`

Comment: It keeps telling me that the element is null and can't read the property.